# Use SQL Server Express engine in MS Access

Tags: sql-server, jet, ms-jet-ace

- Is it possible to use SQL Server Express engine with MS Access?

The reason, why I am asking is, that I want to get rid of **Jet/ACE** engine and the limitation of 2GB per db file.

Thank you for your feedback,

Cralevic

Comment: Nope, but you could migrate [Move Access data to a SQL Server database by using the Upsizing Wizard](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Move-Access-data-to-a-SQL-Server-database-by-using-the-Upsizing-Wizard-5d74c0df-c8cd-4867-8d07-e6e759d72924?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Thank you, but I am not interrested in migrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely Yes, but adp projects are unfortunatelly not supported in Access 2013 and higher. You can use linked tables. But it would be better to migrate e.g. .NET WPF or WinForms project when using SQL database as a backend. See http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/finding-alternatives-to-access-data-projects.html